# Checking for duplicate values within JSON array elements

Tags: jq

I have the following test.json file:

```
[{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"},{"key2":"value2"}]
[{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}]
```

In this, I need to check for duplication only within the array element.

So far, I've tried

```
cat test.json | jq -n 'reduce (inputs|.[]|tostring) as $id ({}; .[$id] += 1) | to_entries[] | select(.value > 1)'
```

This outputs the following:

```
{"key": "{\"key1\":\"value1\"}","value": 2}
{"key": "{\"key2\":\"value2\"}","value": 3}
```

I just need to report

```
{"key": "{\"key2\":\"value2\"}","value": 2}
```

Essentially, `"key2":"value2"` is duplicated only within the array and not across the array elements

Comment: `jq -n 'inputs | reduce (.[]|tostring) as $id ({}; .[$id] += 1) | to_entries[] | select(.value > 1)' test.json` produces the desired output but I'm not sure if you're asking for this

Comment: As @oguzismail indicated, the requirements need to be clarified. What would you want if the same element had been included in the second array? What if the last element in the first array had the same key but a different value?

Comment: Could you clarirfy your expected output? This output doesn't make any sense.. Are you wanting to count the duplicates? 

{
  "key": "{\"key2\":\"value2\"}",
  "value": 2
}

Comment: I'd like to detect if there are any duplicated elements contained in an array. @oguzismail's response outputs my expected result, which I am glad to accept.

Answer (score 0):

The following jq invocation seems to give your expected output:

```
jq -sc '.[]
  | group_by(.)[]
  | select(length > 1)
  | { key: first|tostring, value: length }'
```

Output:

```json
{"key":"{\"key2\":\"value2\"}","value":2}
```